# iOS: different "types" of appWillResignActive notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I have a ViewController that is listening to the UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification.
I have therefore a method that fires when that notification comes.

The thing is that I want to differentiate between these two notifications:
1) app will resign active due to the home button being pressed and the app is not visible
2) app will resign active due to for example an in app purchase alert view, or the user opening the control center or the notification view from the top.

In case 1) I want to "reset" the VC.
In case 2) I do not want to "reset" the VC.

Is there a way to differentiate between those 2 cases?

Comment: Why not reset the VC in `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` which is only triggered in case 1.

Comment: Because, the "old" screen is visible for a fraction of a second before resetting when you use applicationWillEnterForeground or didEnterBackground... which is not "professional" in my opinion. Have you tried it?

Comment: If your vc should refresh when time elapsed, I think it the good place to do the refresh. If you reset the vc in case 1 why don't you reset the vc when app enter foreground after a long time in the background ?

Comment: Good point... I need to move it to the willEnterForeground instead. But what to do with the "old" screen that is visible in a very short period before the reset? maybe a fake splash image?

Comment: You can keep the time that app leaves foreground and check the interval in willEnterForeground method to see if you should reset vc.

Comment: Will, i should reset it under all circumstances, the thing is that the method is called when app willEnterForeground, but for a fraction of a second, you can see the VC being dismissed (the "reset"). it should be dismissed before the app comes to foreground. Hope you understand :)

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, I will play with it, and figure a way to make it work. Think I will add a fake splash screen when appWillEnterForeground, so the thing can dismiss behind the splash screen, and when the splash screen goes away, the vc is finished dismissing. Thanks for your time :) You can write an answer with "use app will enter foreground instead" i will accept it :)

Comment: I think you can't get noticed before that. So the point is how you reset the vc, maybe you can reset it in a smooth way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the view controller should be reset in case 1, I guess it should be reset after a long interval time in the background. So I think it is a good place to do that in `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application`.

To the problem that vc being dismissed when reset, I think there must be a way to work around it, it  depends on how you implements the "reset".